# Dotnet gmail api optional parameters

Tags: .net, gmail, optional-parameters

I am trying to download a raw mail message from gmail, which is not working. The documentation tells me to add the parameter `format = raw` ([source](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)) but when I implement one of these:

```
services.Users.Messages.Get("me", "messageId", format: "raw");
services.Users.Messages.Get("me", "messageId", "raw");
```

Visual Studio will give me the error that "No Overload is possible" (No overload for method 'Get' takes 3 arguments) which makes sense, cause the third argument is not in the metadata-files. But also, I cannot edit these files to add a third (optional) parameter..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The get method (and I assume most of the methods) return an object with properties exposing the optional parameters.

Setting these before calling the `Execute()` method should do the trick. So you would want something like:

```
var request = service.Users.Messages.Get("me", "messageId");
request.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Raw;
var response = request.Execute();
```

There is also an example of setting the "Q" parameter of `messages.list` here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list